# Font Awesome not working in dropdown

Tags: fonts

I'm using Font Awesome in my Laravel app and it works great. However, I'd like to include some of the fonts in a dropdown box (to show "Descending" options) and the icon does not appear. Here's my code:

```
<select id="subject" name="subject">
   <option value="none" selected="selected">(please select an order)</option>
   <option value="emplup">Employee number</option>
   <option value="empldown">Employee number<i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-desc"></i></option>
   <option value="dept">Department</option>
   <option value="deptdown">Department<i class="fa fa-sort-alpha-desc"></i></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default HTML dropdown does not support HTML in options. If you want to have icons and custom look then you need to do some Javascript magic.
Take a look at these jQuery plugins, which could help you http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/dropdown-list

Comment: Thanks for the great link. But in the interest of not adding more plugin weight to my page, I found I could use character entities in the code like this: `<option value="deptdown">Department @darr;</option>`